# In R, how to combine certain strings from multiple columns to be arranged in a long format column by Time within ID?

Tags: r, string, multiple-columns, long-format-data

In R, I would like to select certain strings (A2, D1) from multiple columns (dx1-dx3) and put them in a column in a long format by id while keeping another column (i.e., Time). Below is the data frame.

```
id  dx1 dx2 dx3 Time
1   A2      D1  1
1   B1  A1  D1  2
2   D1          1
2   A3  D1      2
2   A2  D1      3
```

The format I want is as follows:

```
id  name value     Time
1   dx1   A2        1   
1   dx3   D1        1
1   dx3   D1        2
2   dx1   D1        1
2   dx2   D1        2
2   dx1   A2        3
2   dx2   D1        3
```

I tried d %>% select(id, contains('dx'), Time) %>% pivot_longer(cols = -c('id')) %>% filter(str_detect(value, 'A2|D1')). I got the results without the Time column. Do you have any suggestions on how to keep the Time column?

Comment: Your `cols = -c(id, Time)` in `pivot_longer` because `-c(id)` excludes only 'id' column and selects all other columns to be reshaped to 'long'

Comment: Thank you, Akrun! I tried d %>% select(id, contains('dx'), Time) %>% pivot_longer(cols = -c('id', 'Time')) %>% filter(str_detect(value, 'A2|D1'))." It worked! Thank you very much!

Comment: Your `select` statement says you have selected the column.  That code works for me though.  `head(mtcars) %>% select(mpg:vs) %>% pivot_longer(cols = -c(cyl, vs)) %>% nrow#
[1] 36`. I used `packageVersion('tidyr')` as `1.1.3`

Comment: Thank you for your further comments, Akrun! Yes, it worked very well! Sorry, I was too quick on my first shot and forgot to put "Time" in the "select" section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `reshape2::melt` and then subset the rows:

```
library(reshape2)
df = data.frame(id=c(1,1,2,2,2),
                dx1=c('A2','B1','D1','A3','A2'),
                dx2=c(NA, 'A1', NA, 'D1', 'D1'),
                dx3=c('D1','D1',NA, NA, NA),
                Time=c(1,2,1,2,3))
df2 = melt(df, measure.vars=c("dx1","dx2","dx3"), id.vars=c("id","Time"), variable.name="name")
df2 = df2[df2$value %in% c('A2','D1'),]
df2

   id Time name value
1   1    1  dx1    A2
3   2    1  dx1    D1
5   2    3  dx1    A2
9   2    2  dx2    D1
10  2    3  dx2    D1
11  1    1  dx3    D1
12  1    2  dx3    D1
```

Comment: Thank you, Larenite! Your scripts worked too!

Comment: @Grace Glad to hear it! Please accept my answer or upvote it so I can build my reputation score : )

Comment: I am very new to this system. I tried to upvote your answer but it indicates that I need to have more reputation scores to vote. How can I accept your answer?

Comment: No worries! To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Thank you, Larenite! I clicked the check mark. It is now green.